# Business Rules Engine for offline mobile Apps

Tags: mobile, offline, rules

Has anyone come across a slick way of having business rules executed client side in an HTML5 mobile app? 
Our mobile apps have to work when offline and we'd like non-technical people to be able to configure the rules so need a friendly user interface to create the logic.

There are of course plenty of centralized business rules engines out there that would support us when operating online like xpertrule for example but having trouble finding one light enough to run locally on the mobile to support offline use.

DTRules and CLIPS appears light enough but both lack a business ready UI to build the logic. 
Drools may be another but appears difficult to integrate

A slightly different approach that seems attractive are the Intelligent scripting tools like offered by Kirona where the logic is built into a script file that is made available to the client to download and run on the mobile using a script player already embedded in the mobile app.

Wondering if anyone has a similar problem to solve and what conclusions they reached.

Answer (score 0):

I am from XpertRule and I would like to inform you that last year we released exactly what you are looking for, a new business rules engine which is executed client side in an HTML5 mobile app. News release and demo links below.

http://www.xpertrule.com/pages/apps_deploy.htm

http://www.xpertrule.com/deploy/Pension_mobile/description/overview.htm

Please email me if you would like to find out more.

Thanks

Jane

Comment: This is borderline spam. It's advertising your product, but you do disclose your affiliation.

Comment: No spam intended. The question did cite our product XpertRule as a Rules Engine that would work online but not offline running locally on a mobile device. I simply wanted to inform the questioner that XpertRule has a new Javascript rules engine that runs locally as an App on the mobile device.

Comment: I didn't think it was meant as spam - but some members of the community are quite sensitive.